# Group and Sub Group Table in MySQL Select

Tags: mysql

I'm having a Table SalesInvoice. In this Date, Amount Mode are the vital columns in this table.

```
SNo            BID          iDate          Amount         Mode
----------------------------------------------------------------
101             1         2016-01-01        200          Cash
102             2         2016-01-01        500          Credit
103             5         2016-01-01        800          credit
104             8         2016-01-01        250          Cash
105             1         2016-01-01        200          Cash
106             2         2016-01-02        500          Cash
107             5         2016-01-03        800          Credit
108             8         2016-01-03        250          Credit
```

My Required Output is

```
 iDate       MinSno    MaxSno     Total      CreditTotal    CashTotal
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-01     101       105       1950           1300          650
2016-01-02     106       106        500              0          500
2016-01-03     107       108       1050           1050            0
```

I tried the MySQL Query

```
SELECT iDate, Min(SNo) AS MinSno, Max(SNo) AS MaxSno, SUM(Amount) 
From SalesInvoice GROUP By iDate
```

But, I don't know how to get the Sum of Cash and Credit Amount based on Sub Group in the Main Group iDate. Kindly assist me, how to achieve the expected output as mentioned above?

Comment: `SELECT iDate AS Date, Min(SNo) AS MinSno, Max(SNo) AS MaxSno, (CreditTotal+CashTotal) as Total,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM  SalesInvoice where iDate= t1.iDate and Mode='Credit' GROUP By iDate) As CreditTotal,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM  SalesInvoice where iDate= t1.iDate and Mode='Cash' GROUP By iDate) As CashTotal 
From SalesInvoice GROUP By iDate`

Comment: I tried this but, it degrades the performance because I'm having 250K Records in the table. Kindly provide the optimal solution.

Comment: Can you please add index on `iDate` and `Mode` and then check

Comment: My Table is structured as like the same. Here I'm having more than 5000 Distinct iDate, for each row it call the entire table twice to get the SUM of Cash and Credit Amount So, 5000 * 500K Records Processing. So, it degrades the performance. without Credit and Cash Amount, it returns the result 0.029 Seconds. If I implement the Cash and Credit it tooks more than 3 minutes to fetch the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT iDate, min(SNo) as MinSno, max(SNo) as MaxSno, sum(amount) as Total,
sum(If(MMode = 'Cash',Amount,0)) as Cash,
sum(If(MMode = 'Credit',Amount,0)) as Credit
from test.SalesInvoice
Group By iDate;
```

Note that I changed Mode to MMode due to the fact Mode is a keywork in MySQL